# Calculating multiple columns using Panda's mask() and diff() with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`
df:

| Date | Type | AVG1 | AVG2 | AVG3 | AVG4 | AVG5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05 | ROL1 | 0.33 | 0.45 | 0.12 | 0.96 | 1.33 |
| 2022-05 | ROL2 | 1.43 | 0.11 | 0.75 | 1.99 | 3.01 |
| 2022-05 | ROL3 | 0.11 | 0.32 | 0.55 | 1.26 | 4.22 |
| 2022-04 | ROL1 | 1.66 | 0.71 | 0.87 | 5.88 | 1.11 |
| 2022-04 | ROL2 | 2.31 | 0.89 | 2.20 | 4.36 | 4.87 |
| 2022-04 | ROL3 | 5.40 | 1.22 | 4.45 | 0.01 | 0.31 |

And I need to create the columns AVG1_ROL1_MoM, AVG1_ROL2_MoM, AVG3_ROL1_MoM, AVG1_ROL2_MoM and so on. Where AVG1_ROL1_MoM is the difference in AVG1 where TYPE = ROL1 from one month to the other:

| Date | Type | AVG1 | AVG2 | AVG3 | AVG4 | AVG5 | AVG1_ROL1_MoM | AVG1_ROL2_MoM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05 | ROL1 | 0.33 | 0.45 | 0.12 | 0.96 | 1.33 | -1.33 | NaN |
| 2022-05 | ROL2 | 1.43 | 0.11 | 0.75 | 1.99 | 3.01 | NaN | -0.88 |
| 2022-05 | ROL3 | 0.11 | 0.32 | 0.55 | 1.26 | 4.22 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-04 | ROL1 | 1.66 | 0.71 | 0.87 | 5.88 | 1.11 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-04 | ROL2 | 2.31 | 0.89 | 2.20 | 4.36 | 4.87 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-04 | ROL3 | 5.40 | 1.22 | 4.45 | 0.01 | 0.31 | NaN | NaN |

I tried to do that with `mask()` and `shift()`, but it didn't work:

`df['AVG1_ROL1_MoM'] = df.mask(df['Type']=="ROL1", df['AVG1'] - df['AVG1'].shift(), inplace=True)`

This returns that an axis must be defined, but when I define and axis it returns that:
"Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value"

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. `melt` the dataframe to get all the values in a single column
2. Create the new column names
3. `groupby` to find the monthly differences
4. `pivot` to get back the original structure
5. `merge` with the original dataframe

```
melted = df.melt(["Date","Type"])
melted["column"] = melted["variable"]+"_"+melted["Type"]+"_MoM"
melted["diff"] = melted.groupby(["Type","variable"])["value"].diff(-1)

pivoted = melted.pivot(["Date","Type"],"column","diff").sort_index(ascending=[False,True]).reset_index()

output = df.merge(pivoted, on=["Date","Type"])

>>> output
      Date  Type  AVG1  ...  AVG5_ROL1_MoM  AVG5_ROL2_MoM  AVG5_ROL3_MoM
0  2022-05  ROL1  0.33  ...           0.22            NaN            NaN
1  2022-05  ROL2  1.43  ...            NaN          -1.86            NaN
2  2022-05  ROL3  0.11  ...            NaN            NaN           3.91
3  2022-04  ROL1  1.66  ...            NaN            NaN            NaN
4  2022-04  ROL2  2.31  ...            NaN            NaN            NaN
5  2022-04  ROL3  5.40  ...            NaN            NaN            NaN

[6 rows x 22 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

IUUC, you can try group by `Type` column and then compare the subgroup `AVG` shifted value and rename the outcome columns:

```py
out = (df.filter(like='AVG')
       .groupby(df['Type'])
       .apply(lambda g: (g-g.shift(-1)).rename(columns=lambda col: f'{col}_{g.name}_MOM'))
)
```

```
print(out)

   AVG1_ROL1_MOM  AVG2_ROL1_MOM  AVG3_ROL1_MOM  AVG4_ROL1_MOM  AVG5_ROL1_MOM  \
0          -1.33          -0.26          -0.75          -4.92           0.22
1            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
2            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
3            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
4            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
5            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN

   AVG1_ROL2_MOM  AVG2_ROL2_MOM  AVG3_ROL2_MOM  AVG4_ROL2_MOM  AVG5_ROL2_MOM  \
0            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
1          -0.88          -0.78          -1.45          -2.37          -1.86
2            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
3            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
4            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
5            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN

   AVG1_ROL3_MOM  AVG2_ROL3_MOM  AVG3_ROL3_MOM  AVG4_ROL3_MOM  AVG5_ROL3_MOM
0            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
1            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
2          -5.29           -0.9           -3.9           1.25           3.91
3            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
4            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
5            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
```

```py
out = pd.concat([df, out], axis=1)
```

```
print(out)

      Date  Type  AVG1  AVG2  AVG3  AVG4  AVG5  AVG1_ROL1_MOM  AVG2_ROL1_MOM  \
0  2022-05  ROL1  0.33  0.45  0.12  0.96  1.33          -1.33          -0.26
1  2022-05  ROL2  1.43  0.11  0.75  1.99  3.01            NaN            NaN
2  2022-05  ROL3  0.11  0.32  0.55  1.26  4.22            NaN            NaN
3  2022-04  ROL1  1.66  0.71  0.87  5.88  1.11            NaN            NaN
4  2022-04  ROL2  2.31  0.89  2.20  4.36  4.87            NaN            NaN
5  2022-04  ROL3  5.40  1.22  4.45  0.01  0.31            NaN            NaN

   AVG3_ROL1_MOM  AVG4_ROL1_MOM  AVG5_ROL1_MOM  AVG1_ROL2_MOM  AVG2_ROL2_MOM  \
0          -0.75          -4.92           0.22            NaN            NaN
1            NaN            NaN            NaN          -0.88          -0.78
2            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
3            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
4            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
5            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN

   AVG3_ROL2_MOM  AVG4_ROL2_MOM  AVG5_ROL2_MOM  AVG1_ROL3_MOM  AVG2_ROL3_MOM  \
0            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
1          -1.45          -2.37          -1.86            NaN            NaN
2            NaN            NaN            NaN          -5.29           -0.9
3            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
4            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
5            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN

   AVG3_ROL3_MOM  AVG4_ROL3_MOM  AVG5_ROL3_MOM
0            NaN            NaN            NaN
1            NaN            NaN            NaN
2           -3.9           1.25           3.91
3            NaN            NaN            NaN
4            NaN            NaN            NaN
5            NaN            NaN            NaN
```